# Unexpected error while attempting a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've started writing my first unit testing for an if statement, wanting the error to show up if in an input hasn't been entered. Whenever I run the test its been recognised but it's showing as an error with no error message and I'm not sure why.

```
//The test
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace practice_1._0
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyFirstProgramTest
    {
        public const string V = "";

        public object IgnoreCase { get; private set; }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExactResults()
        {
            String expectedAnswer = ("good");
            String expectedAnswer1 = ("bad");
            String expectedAnswer2 = ("poorly");
            string actualAnswer = V;

            Assert.AreEqual(IgnoreCase,expectedAnswer, expectedAnswer1, expectedAnswer2,        actualAnswer,"please Enter an Emotion!");

        }
    }
}
// the if statement
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Tell me how you are?");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userInput == $"Good")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Great, have a good day!");
    }
    else if (userInput == "bad")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey it could be worse!");
     }
    else if (userInput == "poorly")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get better soon!");
    }
    else if (userInput == "no")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oh just tell me!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please! Tell us how you feel!");
    }
```

Comment: Your unit test never calls a method. It tests nothing except maybe itself. Don't do user input in unit tests. It's not a unit test any more. Have you checked the different [overloads of AreEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)? I don't understand what you expect to be equal. I don't see an overload that takes an object and 4 strings.

Comment: I do get an error message: `Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<(null)>. Actual:<good>. bad
   at practice_1._0.MyFirstProgramTest.ExactResults() in UnitTest1.cs:line 21` That's because `IgnoreCase` is `null`. You should really re-think what you're doing. There's so much wrong, it's even hard to decide where to start

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Get started with unit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022&tabs=dotnet%2Cmstest), [Unit test basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2022#write-your-tests), and [Walkthrough: Create and run unit tests for managed code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this piece of code will guide you to the idea of ​​unit tests and how to do them correctly.Firstly I extracted your if statemnt to method:

```
public string IfStatment(string userInput)
    {
        if (userInput == $"Good")
        {
            return "Great, have a good day!";
        }
        else if (userInput == "bad")
        {
            return"Hey it could be worse!";
        }
        else if (userInput == "poorly")
        {
            return"Get better soon!";
        }
        else if (userInput == "no")
        {
        return"Oh just tell me!";
        }
        else
        {
            return"please! Tell us how you feel!";
        }
    }
```

then write simple test checking all possibilities

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMEthod()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Great, have a good day!",IfStatment("Good"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Hey it could be worse!",IfStatment("bad"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Get better soon!",IfStatment("poorly"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Oh just tell me!",IfStatment("no"));
        Assert.AreEqual("random string",IfStatment("please! Tell us how you feel!"));
    }
```

please take into account that this is just an example of how you can solve this problem, but as suggested you should get the hang of the basics first